# Использование сессий и уменьшение флуда

Tags: php, c++, mysql, сессия

Несколько php скриптов представляет собой API.
Пользователь, чтобы получить ответ, должен отправить два запроса (их требует специфика приложения).

- 1 запрос: будет создан ключ
- 2 запрос: используя ключ будет полученные данные.

Сейчас работает так:

- после создания ключа он записывается в базу данных.
- второй запрос ищет его в базе. Если найдет - удаляет и проходит дальнейшая обработка данных, иначе ошибка.

Кроме того, ключ валидный всего несколько минут.
Здесь проблема: пользователь может отправлять запросы только первого типа и тогда база ключей будет постоянно нарастать. Конечно, сейчас реализована cron задача по удалению лишних ключей.

**Можно ли использовать сессии в этом случаи**, чтобы избежать базы ключей?

Забегая наперед скажу, что пользовательская часть будет написанная на С++.
**Как получить идентификатор сессии**, чтобы используясь его отправить второй запрос (GET/POST)?

Comment: Идентификатор сессии пользователю посылайте в куках. Собственно там и берите. Как именно будете это делать - а кто его знает, все сильно зависит от того, какими библиотеками будете пользоваться.

А вот для хранения ключей можно использовать memcache или redis. Там удаление устаревших данных - встроенная функция. То есть, добавляете  memcache ключ и говорите - хранить две минуты. И все готово.

Хотя можно ключи совсем не хранить, а шифровать время создания. По получению - декодировать. Если все правильно сделать - будет легко. но немного уязвимо.

Comment: @KoVadim подключать целую библиотеку ради 1 функции не очень хочется.
Шифрования даты возьму на заметку. А почему будет уязвимо?

Comment: redis/memcache - это не библиотека:) погуглите. Но возможно (попахивает преждевременной оптимизацией), что memcache понадобиться в будущем.

А шифрование будет уязвимо, если его вскроют. Но это зависит от надобности Вашего проекта.

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо.

Comment: @KoVadim заметил большую дыру в методе через шифровку. Как я сказал ключ действует несколько минут. Если после первого запроса получить шифрованный ключ (я шифровал время и ip), то им можно пользоваться (отправлять запрос второго вида) много раз на протяжении нескольких минут. Второй запрос, кроме получения, записывает информацию в базу, которую уже не можно удалять через cron. В результате неправильных данных еще больше.

Comment: что вы тут такое говорите человеку, сессии же для этого и создавались... чем плохо то

при начале:

    $_SESSION['mysecretkey']=array('expire'=>time()+600,'value'=>$keyvalue);

при проверке

    if (time>()expire) {удаляем 'mysecretkey' из $_SESION или ошибку выдаем;exit;}
    //тут делаем все остальное

ключи так-же можно хранить в базе или в tmpfs, можно настроить мусорщик чтобы он почаще удалял устаревшие сессии.

шифровать смысла нет никакого. если к вашему серверу получат доступ то получат доступ и к ключам шифрования (ну или вы их расшифровать не сможете)

Comment: @eicto просто не очень правильно использовать сессии в api. Ключи сейчас и хранятся в базе и выходит, что неиспользуемых ключей может быть очень много, т.к капча отсутствует. Сам ключ ни с чем не связан (чисто случайные данные) Посмотрю в сторону memcached.

Comment: @dal, сессия это вообще не какая-то функция, это шаблон, то что вы хотите всё равно будет сессией, так почему бы не разрешить делать его и через куки и через GET параметр ?

Answer (score 1):

Не желательно использовать куки, иначе от API не будет смысла по логике. А вообще лучше бы конечно объединить ваши 2 шага в один, или как в ВК, использовать один токен.

Comment: @Manitikyl два шага требуется. Буду шифровать данные.

Comment: В любом случае это БД. БД для того и создавалось чтобы работать с множеством данным и динамически добавлять/удалять, не думаю что вы сумеете нагрузить так сильно свою БД. Поэтому желательно оставьте как есть, данный алгоритм вполне приемлемый.